# Sending notification Firebase with "data" and "notification"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the best way to send a notification with firebase? If i use only `notification` parameter, am i sure that this will arrive when the app is closed, in background, or foreground?
I read somewhere that if you use `data` parameter the `notification` is always received. But in my phone seems the same with only the `notification` parameter. What should i use? My priority is that the notification always show up. Thanks!

Comment: use data node to receive notification and handle the data. notification node only work when your application is closed and it is auto-generated why system tray, I advise you to check the doc once more time.

Comment: Thank you so much. But notification seems to work in every situation during my tests. it depends on the phone model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) you can see the answer to how it is handled according to the use of the `notification` or `data` fields.

Anyway, these two fields are used for different purposes:

- `notification` contains, simplifying, the title and the text of the notification that should appear in the system tray. If the notification contains only this field, then if the app is in background, then it'll be shown in the system tray, if it's in the foreground it'll be passed to a method, and then you can decide what to do (including to show it)
- `data` contains a list of key-value pairs, that should be directly used by your app. If your notification contains only this field, the notification will be passed to your app directly, independently if the app is in the foreground or the background

Finally, if it contains both, then if the app is in the foreground, then the notification is passed to your app and you can decide what to do with it (including showing it, as it seems you want), and if it's in the background it'll be shown in the system tray and the `data` part is delivered in the extras of the intent of the launcher Activity.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! The last question : when the app is closed, if I use notification OR data parameter, the notification will always be shown?

Comment: @Dev9977 If the app is closed and you want to be sure that the notification is shown you need to define at least the "notification" part. Because this part will be read by the OS to show the title and text in the system tray

Comment: Thank you! Then if I use the notification parameter without data, and I define it in the code, the notification will always be shown? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need the "data" payload, then yes, you can just skip it. You need also to consider that if your app is in the foreground, then the notification will not be shown automatically, but you can decide to do it from code